# Something similar to ParallelPython for C++?

Tags: c++, python, distributed, cluster-computing

I need to do some extensive searching and string comparisons and for this I figure that a compiled program is much better than an interpreted ones especially after seeing some comparison studies. I came across [ParallelPython](http://www.parallelpython.com/) which was beautiful. It has autodiscovery for clusters and can pretty much do all the load balancing for me as well.

My first question is, is it a good idea to just go ahead with Python on a cluster having 20 nodes or do I switch to C++? If I need to switch then is there a good alternative to ParallelPython for C++ that provides features like load balancing and autodiscovery for node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [OpenMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/). I do not know what ParallelPython does exactly, but OpenMPI is an open API for cluster computing, and I imagine it will provide the requested functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use ParallelPython for your high level work, and call into C++ code for the "hard-core" processing, as needed.

That being said, there are options in the C++ world.  The most common cluster-based technology is [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface).  Some implementations provide load balancing and auto-discovery, though it's not in the core spec.